# Get parameter name in Clion plugin

Tags: plugins, clion

I am developing a plugin for Clion (C++) that needs to access caller parameter name, e.g. if a function is declared:

```
void fun(int a);
```

and called

```
fun(42);
```

when the intent is invoked on `42` `PsiElement` it should get the corresponding parameter name, `"a"` in this case.

In a similar plugin for Intellij (Java), I get the parameter name with `PsiCallExpression.resolveMethod()` which contains the list of parameters. However, I cannot figure out how to do this in a Clion plugin. I can get a reference of a corresponding `OCCallExpression`, but it does not seem to contain a reference to the declared function. I tried to play around with `ReferencesSearch.search()`, but it did not find the declaration of the function.

At the same time, the IDE itself displays all the parameter name hints:
[image: parameter hints in Clion] so I suppose it must be possible.

How can I get the parameter name for a given caller argument expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, look at `InlayParameterHintsExtension.forLanguage(OCLanguage.getInstance())` and `InlayParameterHintsProvider.getParameterHints`

Comment: It works well if parameter hints are enabled in Clion. However, if they are turned off, then getParameterHints() returns an empty list. Is there a way to get param name even if parameter hints are disabled?

Comment: In this case you need to look at 
`com.intellij.codeInsight.navigation.actions.GotoDeclarationHandler#getGotoDeclarationTargets` and Psi-tree analyzing. The call is expensive and need to be cancellable and executed in background.